# accordion display to find the next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Progress: https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/jstuq9ok/4/

There are probably a few ways to do this but I have a class called sub that I add to hide a 'nested' Div and then use jQuery to toggle the Glyphicon along with display the 'nested' Div. Some asks:

```
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-up');
  //How to do something like this to traverse the click and structure $(this).parent.find('.sub:first-child').toggle();
  $('.sub').toggle();
  $('.subsecond').toggle();
});
```

The nested team structure intended is this:

1. Adam
2. Lily

   2.1 Sen

   2.1.1 Tank

   2.2 Another Sen
3. Justin

What I'm trying to do do is have this traverse through the DOM based on where the click happens to display the sub section under there. I have the content coming from a source system so can't hard code class directly.

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Are you sure you have a `nested` divs?? from your demo I found all your divs in the same level

Comment: Hi Mohamed- You are correct. I should clarify what I meant- visually nested div not structurally. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: @zigzag can't you any library like jQuery-ui to achieve your accordion display ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the next div by using `.closest('.row')` *to get the parent .row* and `.next('.row')` *to get the next .row of the parent .row* if it has class or not using `hasClass()` so you can use

```
$('.menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // prevent <a> to redirect to the top of the page
  $('.row:not(.sub):not(.subsecond)').not($('.sub').prev('.row')).not($('.subsecond').prev('.row')).not($(this).closest('.row')).find('span.glyphicon-menu-up').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-menu-up');
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-menu-up');
  var Nextrow = $(this).closest('.row').next('.row');  // get the next row
  if(Nextrow.hasClass('sub')){   // if next row has class sub
    $('.sub').not(Nextrow).hide();  // hide all sub but not this one
    Nextrow.slideToggle(function(){
      if($(this).is(':hidden')){ // check if the .sub is hidden 
        $('.subsecond').hide();  // hide subsecond
        $('span.glyphicon-menu-up').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-menu-up');  // toggle arrows to the down
      }
    });      // toggle this sub row
    return false;
  }
  if(Nextrow.hasClass('subsecond')){ // if next row has class subsecond
    $('.subsecond').not(Nextrow).hide(); // hide all subsecond but not this one
    Nextrow.slideToggle();   // toggle this subsecond row
    return false;
  }
});
```

[**See Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/jstuq9ok/9/)

Comment: hah! Clever! Love it. One question- I notice that once all three levels open, clicking on the first node hides the second but keeps the third. how do you avoid that?

Comment: @zigzag you're right nice catch .. and problems with arrows as well :-) .. I'll solve that .. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Mohammed! I see the v9 works. Appreciate it.

Comment: Yo Mo, one more wrench on this one- if there is someone at the same level as Shen, in this case called "another Shen" right under the markup for Shen it doesn't seem to display it right. Am I placing the markup at the wrong place or is there a better way to change the script? https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/jstuq9ok/10/

Comment: made more progress- https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/jstuq9ok/11/ Now just need to address this for subsecond area to display also. If you now click on Lily, shen and another shen show up but if you now click on shen to drill down, it just hides it. thoughts?